# remove method of doublylinkedlist throwing exception java

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

so i have a doublylinkedlist in java and i'm testing it but when i decided to remove two elements at the same index it throwed a null pointer exception

this is my list [ A, B, C, D, E]
and this is my test

```
System.out.println("Item removed at index 3: " + list.removeAtIndex(3));
System.out.println(list);
//throws exception at following line
System.out.println("Item removed at index 3: " + list.removeAtIndex(3));
System.out.println(list);
```

list should be [ A, B, C]
but it throws an exception
here is my implementation of the removeAtIndex method

```
public E removeAtIndex(int index) {
    DoublyLinkedNode<E> node = firstNode;
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        node = node.getNext();
    }
    E item = node.getItem();
    node.getPrevious().setNext(node.getNext());
    node.getNext().setPrevious(node.getPrevious());
    return item;
 }
```

how can i work this out?

Edit: i forgot to say, that when i delete at one index and then again but at a different index it works just fine

Comment: What is the exception thrown ?

Comment: Why not use Java's standard [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) which is doubly linked ist ?

Comment: @Santosh thrown exception is null pointer exception as i say in the question, also i don't use linkedList as i'm trying to learn how it works first and writing it from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect one issue:

You are not using sentinel (dummy) header and tail nodes. So when you remove from the end and call

```
node.getNext().setPrevious(node.getPrevious());
node.getNext();//actually returns null at the end of a list
```

You will need to check for null after you call the getNext and getPrevious methods

Comment: yep, that was it, i wasn't checking for null in node.getNext() so i added an if statement and it solved the problem, thank you very much :)